# Sort by SUM(col) of different table - FetchAll only returns first result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table of e-sporting events, `game_events`, and the total amount of sponsored/pledged money for each event can be calculated from the `cash_pledges` table.

This query works, but it only returns the first result from the `game_events` table, even when using `FetchAll()`. I would like to fetch all matching events and sort them by their `total_pot` field created from `SUM(amount)`.

```
$query = 'SELECT * , 
                SUM(cash_pledges.amount) AS total_pot 
           FROM game_events 
             INNER JOIN cash_pledges 
           WHERE cash_pledges.event=game_events.id  
           ORDER BY total_pot DESC';
$r = $pdb->Query($query)->FetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    game_events.*, 
    SUM(cash_pledges.amount) AS total_pot 
FROM game_events 
    INNER JOIN cash_pledges 
WHERE cash_pledges.event=game_events.id
GROUP BY game_events.id
ORDER BY total_pot DESC
```

Otherwise only a single result with the sum of all cash_pledges.amounts will be returned.